# Keras custom loss function with binary (round) with tensorflow backend

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, loss

I'm currently trying to implement a custom loss function (precision) with a binary outcome but Tensorflow backend refuses to use round function which is necessary to be used in order to generate a '0' or '1'.

As far as I have investigated, this is because Tensorflow defines the gradient of the round as None and the loss function can't return None.

I have currently implemented this custom loss to create as close as is possible '0' or '1'  in R Keras interface.

```
precision_loss<-function(y_true,y_pred){
  y_pred_pos = K$clip(y_pred, 0, 1)
  #Custom sigmoid to generate '0' '1'
  y_pred_pos =  K$maximum(0,K$minimum(1,(y_pred_pos+0.0625)/0.125))
  y_pred_neg = 1 - y_pred_pos
  y_pos = K$clip(y_true, 0, 1)
  #Custom sigmoid to generate '0' '1'
  y_pos =  K$maximum(0,K$minimum(1,(y_pos+0.0625)/0.125))
  y_neg = 1 - y_pos
  #Generate confusion matrix counts
  tp = K$sum(y_pos*y_pred_pos)
  tn = K$sum(y_neg*y_pred_neg)
  fp = K$sum(y_neg*y_pred_pos)
  fn = K$sum(y_pos*y_pred_neg)
  return(1-(tp/(tp+fp+K$epsilon())))
}
```

Notice the "sigmoid" : K$maximum(0,K$minimum(1,(y_pos+0.0625)/0.125))

What I wanted to implement is a workaround for this one:

```
precision_loss<-function(y_true, y_pred){
  y_pred_pos = K$round(K$clip(y_pred, 0, 1))
  y_pred_neg = 1 - y_pred_pos
  y_pos = K$round(K$clip(y_true, 0, 1))
  y_neg = 1 - y_pos
  #Generate confusion matrix counts
  tp = K$sum(K$clip(y_pos * y_pred_pos,0,1))
  tn = K$sum(K$clip(y_neg * y_pred_neg,0,1))
  fp = K$sum(K$clip(y_neg * y_pred_pos,0,1))
  fn = K$sum(K$clip(y_pos * y_pred_neg,0,1))
  return(1-(tp/(tp+fp+K$epsilon())))
}
```

Some of you have an alternative implementation without using round to generate binary outcomes in the loss function?

PD: In custom metrics function the round is allowed

Answer (score 1):

In order to build a binary loss function, it wouldn't be enough to just build the custom loss function itself. You would also have to pre-define the gradients.

Your high-dimensional loss function would be zero for some points and one for all others. For all **non-continuous** points in this space, it would be impossible to analytically compute a gradient (i.e. the concept of a gradient doesn't even exist for such points), so you would have to just define one. And for all the **continuous** points in this space (e.g. an open set in which all loss values are 1), the gradient would exist, but it would be zero, so you would also have to pre-define the gradient values, otherwise your weights wouldn't move at all.

That means either way you would have to define your own custom "gradient" computation function that replaces Keras' (i.e. TensorFlow's) automatic differentiation engine for that particular node in the graph (the loss function node).

You could certainly achieve this by modifying your local copy of Keras or TensorFlow, but nothing good can come from it.

Also, even if you managed to do this, consider this: If your loss function returns only 0 or 1, that means it can only distinguish between two states: The model's prediction is either 100% correct (0 loss) or it is not 100% correct (1 loss). The magnitude of the gradient would have to be the same for all non-100% cases. Is that a desirable property?

Your quasi-binary sigmoid solution has the same problem: The gradient will be almost zero almost everywhere, and in the few points where it won't be almost zero, it will be almost infinity. If you try to train a model with that loss function, it won't learn anything.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed a **custom loss function** need to be **based on functions which have their gradients defined** (in order to minimise the loss function), which is **not necessary for a simple metric**. Some functions like **“round” and “sign”** are difficult to use in loss function since their gradients are either null all the time or infinite which is not helpful for minimisation. That’s probably why **their gradients are not defined**, by default.

Then, you have two options:

- Option 1: you use the *round* function but you need to add your custom gradient for *round*, to substitute it in backend.
- Option 2: you define another loss function without using *round*

You chose option 2, which is the best option I think. But your “sigmoid” is very linear, so probably, not a good approximation of your “round” function. You could use an actual sigmoid which is slower due to the use of exponential but you could obtain a similar result with a modified softsign:

> max_gradient=100
>
> K$maximum(0,K$minimum(1,0.5*(1+(max_gradient*y_pos)/(1+ max_gradient*abs(y_pos)))))

The max_gradient coefficient can be used to make your edge more sharp, around 0.5. It defines the maximum gradient at 0.5.